# Get latest from Git branch

Tags: git

I cloned something from git repository, and switched branch

```
git clone ssh://11.21.3.12:23211/dir1/dir2 dir
git branch branch1
```

I did some modification in my local, and committed it. And somebody else also done clone and he pushed it in git repository.

Now I want the clone copy of branch1 in my local, (means don't want my update, but his update)

Comment: you mean like `git push origin branch1`?

Comment: Ah sorry, thought you wanted to push your update.

Comment: no, i don't want my update. I just want his update only.

Comment: you just want to "get latest" from the central location right? -- Title says it all.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Your modifications are in a different branch than the original branch, which simplifies stuff because you get updates in one branch, and your work is in another branch.

Assuming the original branch is named `master`, which the case in 99% of git repos, you have to fetch the state of origin, and merge `origin/master` updates into your local `master`:

```
 git fetch origin
 git checkout master
 git merge origin/master
```

To switch to your branch, just do

```
 git checkout branch1
```

Comment: @Surendhar, Seriously, try to learn to `fetch/merge`. `pull` will one day give you trouble and you would be too used to it to change to `fetch/merge`

Comment: er... that just did nothing -- it says it's already up to date, already in master, etc. -- it's been like a year since I cloned this branch, and I know there's been a ton of changes.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 you don't clone a branch, but a repository. make sure that the remote points to the expected URL with `git remote -v`

Comment: After performing commands above here, I noticed, in the git directory that the HEAD, index, and packed-refs files are different.  Is this just to track related branches?

Comment: @RetroCoder You fetched modifications from remote repository, so it's normal that these references are updated to acknowledge for new objects. HEAD is updated each time you checkout a branch, or make a new commit

Comment: Ah.. So it just shows what local branches I've been stashing at that directory tree may be different from the local branches on another directory tree even though they have the latest fetch and checkout of an origin/master branch on both.

Answer (score 49):

use git pull:

```
git pull origin yourbranch
```

Answer (score 16):

Although `git pull origin yourbranch` works, it's [not really a good idea](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/)

You can alternatively do the following:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/yourbranch
```

The first line fetches all the branches from origin, but doesn't merge with your branches. This simply completes your copy of the repository.

The second line merges your current branch with that of `yourbranch` that you fetched from `origin` (which is one of your `remotes`).

This is assuming `origin` points to the repository at address `ssh://11.21.3.12:23211/dir1/dir2`

Comment: when I merge it say   * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD. Any solution?

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY please ask a new question with more details.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `git fetch` to get all available branches.
2. Checkout to desired branch using `git checkout <branch>`
3. Then, `git pull origin <branch>` to get latest changes.

Note:- if your branch is up-to-date with remote branch, you will see the below.

```
Already up to date.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want the pull to overwrite local changes, doing the merge as if the working tree were clean, well, clean the working tree:

```
git reset --hard
git pull
```

If there are untracked local files you could use git clean to remove them.

`git clean -f` to remove untracked files
`-df` to remove untracked files and directories
`-xdf` to remove untracked or ignored files or directories

If on the other hand you want to keep the local modifications somehow, you'd use stash to hide them away before pulling, then reapply them afterwards:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

I don't think it makes any sense to literally ignore the changes, though - half of pull is merge, and it needs to merge the committed versions of content with the versions it fetched.

Answer (score -3):

If you have forked a repository fro Delete your forked copy and fork it again from master.